# Find table containining a certain cell in ms sql server?

Tags: sql-server

There is a cell that contains NTC or NCELL. I need to find the name of the table in which the table is.

I've been using this to find table name given column name.

```
SELECT
    ColumnName = c.name,
    SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),
    TableName = t.name
FROM 
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    c.name = 'your-column-name-here'
```

How do I modify it to find table name given cell name?

Comment: Just to clarify: You are looking for 1. Way to find tables that have columns whose *name* contains your string? OR 2. tables containing fields that contains your string as data?

Comment: Your #2 is what I am looking for

Comment: So what you're saying is that you know that literal string 'NTC' or 'NCELL' exists in some unknown column of some unknown table in your database, is that correct?

Comment: yes @McA-the-dba

Answer (score 0):

There's no system objects that you can query to find information about the values of the data in the tables, like you're currently doing to find column names. You'd instead have to query every column of every table, which can be done with dynamic SQL. It is somewhat of a tedious process and not quick, since every data point is being queried.

For goals like this, I prefer to just export the data as scripts using the Database Task feature of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). You can accomplish this with the following:

1. In SSMS, right click your database and click on Tasks, then click on Generate scripts...
2. On the "Choose Objects" screen, select specific objects and checkoff the Tables checkbox to select all tables.
3. On the "Set Scripting Options" screen, select Save as script file, then One script file per object, then select a file path to save the scripts to.
4. On the same screen, click the Advanced button, and under the Types of data to script change the drop-down to Data only.
5. Click Next and then Finish for it to begin scripting out the data of your database.

Once it finishes, you can use a file search tool like [AstroGrep](https://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) to easily find which table contains the data you're looking for. Once you open that specific script file, you can see which column it's in as well. If you know certain tables definitely don't contain the data you're looking for, you can speed up the generation process by only selecting a subset of applicable tables in Step 2, by expanding the Tables node and checking off individual objects.

For more information with screenshots, please see the docs on [Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-and-publish-scripts-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16).